# Adding an xls filename to a column in python

Tags: python, excel

I have some code that carries out this task for .csv (thanks to Michal K for assistance).

Any ideas on how I could change this to work on a directory of .xls files rather than .csv files?

```
import csv
import os

for file_name in os.listdir("c:/projects/files"):
    with open(file_name,'r') as csvinput:
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('FileName')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(file_name)
            all.append(row)

    with open(file_name, 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/)

Comment: the objective does not seem clear to me. do you want to control the path of files? or deal with excel files?

Comment: Leonard2 - thanks for commenting. Rather than adding a new column containing the file name to .csv files (as the above script does) I would like to be able to do this on .xls files instead

Comment: working with csv and xls is totally different; csv is just plain text, but xls is a certain format defined by Microsoft (AFAIK, xlsx is XML based). thus to deal with xls, you need to take your time to see what module works and how it works. it seems that your answers are providing good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Excel spreadsheets are slightly more complicated than CSV files, so I'd recommend using an imported module such as [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/).

This allows you to get the worksheets (tabs) from the file, and manipulate the columns and rows as you see fit.

The general program structure would look something like this:

```
for file_name in os.listdir("c:/projects/files"):
    if file_name.endswith('.xls'):
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)

        # Get worksheets
        # Manipulate columns and rows

        workbook.save(file_name)
```

There's a really good tutorial on using openpyxl [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/)

Answer (score 0):

for reading and writing excel and csv files, `pandas` is very convenient

```
import pandas as pd
```

## csv

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, header=0) # you can define the exact csv format with further arguments
csv_data['filename'] = csv_filename  #adds a column with the filename
```

## excel

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel(excel_filename)
excel_data['filename'] = excel_filename
```

## export

```
csv_data.to_csv(output_csv)
excel_data.to_excel(output_excel)
```

You can also export the csv to excel or vice versa

```
excel_data.to_csv(output_excel_csv)
csv_data.to_excel(output_csv_excel)
```